# Mock api in react redux-thunk project returning undefined

Tags: ajax, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I am quite new in redux world and have not yet had a project structured the [ducks](https://github.com/erikras/ducks-modular-redux) way. I am trying to understand it and use it to make a mock api, since I don't have the backend ready yet. I am working with the legacy code, that I am trying to figure out. There is a folder called data, that has a `duck` and a `backendApi` file. Duck file looks like this.

**data/duck.jsx**

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';
import { createReduxApi } from './backendApi';

const getDataContext = state => state.default.dataContext;

const backendReduxApi = createBackendReduxApi(getDataContext);

// Action creators
export const makeRestApiRequest = endpointName => backendReduxApi .makeRequestActionCreator(endpointName);

export const resetRestApi = endpointName => backendReduxApi .makeResetActionCreator(endpointName);

// Reducers
export const dataReducer = backendReduxApi .createReducer();

// Selectors
const getRestApiState = endpointName => backendReduxApi .getEndpointState(endpointName);
export const getRestApiData = endpointName => createSelector([getRestApiState(endpointName)], apiState => apiState.data);
export const getRestApiMeta = endpointName => createSelector([getRestApiState(endpointName)], apiState => apiState.meta);
export const getRestApiError = endpointName => createSelector([getRestApiState(endpointName)], apiState => apiState.error);
export const getRestApiStarted = endpointName => createSelector([getRestApiState(endpointName)], apiState => apiState.started);
export const getRestApiFinished = endpointName => createSelector([getRestApiState(endpointName)], apiState => apiState.finished);
```

The `backendApi.jsx` file looks like this:

**data/backendApi.jsx**

```
import ReduxRestApi from './rest/ReduxRestApi';

export const BackendApi = { // NOSONAR
  LANGUAGE_FILE: 'languageFile',
  EMPLOYEE: 'employee',
};

const backendReduxApiBuilder = ReduxRestApi.build()
  /* /api */

  /* /api/employee */
  .withGet('/myproject/api/employee', BackendApi.EMPLOYEE)

  /* /language*/
  .withGet('/myproject/language/nb_NO.json', BackendApi.LANGUAGE_FILE)

export const createBackendReduxApi = restApiSelector => backendReduxApiBuilder
  .withRestApiSelector(restApiSelector)
  .create();
```

Then in the `data/rest` folder I have 4 files: `ReduxRestApi`, `restConfig`, `RestDuck` and `restMethods`.

**data/rest/ReduxRestApi.jsx**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { get, post, postAndOpenBlob } from './restMethods';
import RestDuck from './RestDuck';

class ReduxRestApi {
  constructor(endpoints, getRestApiState) {
    this.createReducer = this.createReducer.bind(this);
    this.getEndpoint = this.getEndpoint.bind(this);
    this.makeRequestActionCreator = this.makeRequestActionCreator.bind(this);
    this.makeResetActionCreator = this.makeResetActionCreator.bind(this);
    this.getEndpointState = this.getEndpointState.bind(this);
    this.ducks = endpoints.map(({ name, path, restMethod }) => new RestDuck(name, path, restMethod, getRestApiState));
  }

  createReducer() {
    const reducers = this.ducks
      .map(duck => ({ [duck.name]: duck.reducer }))
      .reduce((a, b) => ({ ...a, ...b }), {});
    return combineReducers(reducers);
  }

  getEndpoint(endpointName) {
    return this.ducks.find(duck => duck.name === endpointName)
      || { actionCreators: {} };
  }

  makeRequestActionCreator(endpointName) {
    return this.getEndpoint(endpointName).actionCreators.execRequest;
  }

  makeResetActionCreator(endpointName) {
    return this.getEndpoint(endpointName).actionCreators.reset;
  }

  getEndpointState(endpointName) {
    return this.getEndpoint(endpointName).stateSelector;
  }

  static build() {
    class RestApiBuilder {
      constructor() {
        this.withGet = this.withGet.bind(this);
        this.withPost = this.withPost.bind(this);
        this.withPostAndOpenBlob = this.withPostAndOpenBlob.bind(this);
        this.withRestApiSelector = this.withRestApiSelector.bind(this);
        this.endpoints = [];
      }

      withGet(path, name) {
        this.endpoints.push({ path, name, restMethod: get });
        return this;
      }

      withPost(path, name) {
        this.endpoints.push({ path, name, restMethod: post });
        return this;
      }

      withPostAndOpenBlob(path, name) {
        this.endpoints.push({ path, name, restMethod: postAndOpenBlob });
        return this;
      }

      withRestApiSelector(restApiSelector) {
        this.restApiSelector = restApiSelector;
        return this;
      }

      create() {
        return new ReduxRestApi(
          this.endpoints,
          this.restApiSelector
        );
      }
    }

    return new RestApiBuilder();
  }
}

export default ReduxRestApi;
```

**restConfig.jsx**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { removeErrorMessage, showErrorMessage } from '../../app/duck';
import { is401Error, isHandledError } from '../../app/ErrorTypes';

const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';

const configureRequestInterceptors = (store) => {
  const onRequestAccepted = (config) => {
    store.dispatch(removeErrorMessage());
    return config;
  };

  const onRequestRejected = error => Promise.reject(error);

  axios.interceptors.request.use(onRequestAccepted, onRequestRejected);
};

const configureResponseInterceptors = (store) => {
  const onSuccessResponse = response => response;

  const onErrorResponse = (error) => {
    if (is401Error(error) && !isDevelopment) {
      window.location.reload();
    }
    if (!isHandledError(error)) {
      store.dispatch(showErrorMessage(error));
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  };

  axios.interceptors.response.use(onSuccessResponse, onErrorResponse);
};

const configureRestInterceptors = (store) => {
  configureRequestInterceptors(store);
  configureResponseInterceptors(store);
};

export default configureRestInterceptors;
```

**data/rest/RestDuck.jsx**

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

import { get, getBlob, post, postAndOpenBlob, postBlob } from './restMethods';

/**
 * getMethodName
 * Helper function that maps given AJAX-method to a name
 *
 * Ex. getMethodName(getBlob) -> 'GET'
 */
const getMethodName = (restMethod) => {
  switch (restMethod) {
    case get:
    case getBlob:
      return 'GET';
    case post:
    case postBlob:
    case postAndOpenBlob:
      return 'POST';
    default:
      return '';
  }
};

/**
 * createRequestActionType
 * Helper function to generate actionType for actions related to AJAX calls
 *
 * Ex: createRequestActionType('fetchEmployee', 'ERROR', get, '/myproject/api/employee') -> '@@REST/fetchEmployee GET /myproject/api/employeeERROR'
 */
const createRequestActionType = (name, qualifier, restMethod = '', path = '') => [`@@REST/${name}`, getMethodName(restMethod), path, qualifier]
  .filter(s => s !== '')
  .join(' ');

/**
 * createRequestActionTypes
 * Helper function to generate ActionTypes for a given AJAX method and resource.
 *
 * Ex. createRequestActionType(fetchEmployee, get, '/myproject/api/employee') -> {
 *   reset: '@@REST GET /myproject/api/employee RESET',
 *   requestStarted: '@@REST GET /myproject/api/employee STARTED',
 *   requestError: '@@REST GET /myproject/api/employee ERROR',
 *   requestFinished: '@@REST GET /myproject/api/employee FINISHED',
 * }
 */
const createRequestActionTypes = (name, restMethod, path) => ({
  reset: createRequestActionType(name, 'RESET'),
  requestStarted: createRequestActionType(name, 'STARTED', restMethod, path),
  requestError: createRequestActionType(name, 'ERROR', restMethod, path),
  requestFinished: createRequestActionType(name, 'FINISHED', restMethod, path)
});

/**
 * createRequestThunk
 * Helper function that generates a thunk that performs an AJAX call specified by 'restMethod' and 'restEndpoint'
 *
 * When the thunk is running, the action 'requestStarted' will be dispatched immediately.
 * Then, it performs the AJAX call that returns a promise.
 *  If the call goes well, the action 'requestFinished' will be dispatched with data from the call.
 * If the call fails, the action 'requestError' is dispatched with the contents of the error.
 */
const createRequestThunk = (restMethod, restEndpoint, requestStarted, requestFinished, requestError) => (
  (params, options = {}) => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(requestStarted(params, options));
    return restMethod(restEndpoint, params)
      .catch((error) => {
        const data = error.response && error.response.data ? error.response.data : error;
        dispatch(requestError(data));
        return Promise.reject(error);
      })
      .then((response) => {
        dispatch(requestFinished(response.data));
        return response;
      });
  }
);

/**
 * createRequestActionCreators
 * Helper function that creates action creators 'requestStarted', 'requestFinished' and 'requestError',
 * @see createRequestThunkCreator
 */
const createRequestActionCreators = (restMethod, restEndpoint, actionTypes) => {
  const reset = () => ({ type: actionTypes.reset });
  const requestStarted = (params, options = {}) => ({ type: actionTypes.requestStarted, payload: { params, timestamp: Date.now() }, meta: { options } });
  const requestFinished = data => ({ type: actionTypes.requestFinished, payload: data });
  const requestError = error => ({ type: actionTypes.requestError, payload: error });
  const execRequest = createRequestThunk(restMethod, restEndpoint, requestStarted, requestFinished, requestError);
  return {
    reset, requestStarted, requestFinished, requestError, execRequest
  };
};

/**
 * createRequestReducer
 *
 * Helper function that creates a reducer for an AJAX call.
 * Reducer alters the state of the actions with the name defined by
 *   actionTypes.requestStarted
 *   actionTypes.requestFinished
 *   actionTypes.requestError
 */
const createRequestReducer = (restMethod, resourceName, actionTypes) => {
  const initialState = {
    data: undefined,
    meta: undefined,
    error: undefined,
    started: false,
    finished: false
  };

  return (state = initialState, action = {}) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case actionTypes.requestStarted:
        return {
          ...initialState,
          data: action.meta.options.keepData ? state.data : initialState.data,
          started: true,
          meta: action.payload
        };
      case actionTypes.requestFinished:
        return {
          ...state,
          started: false,
          finished: true,
          data: action.payload
        };
      case actionTypes.requestError:
        return {
          ...state,
          started: false,
          error: action.payload
        };
      case actionTypes.reset:
        return {
          ...initialState
        };
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };
};

/**
 * RestDuck
 * Class that offers action types, action creators, reducers and selectors for an AJAX call.
 * @see createRequestActionTypes
 * @see createRequestActionCreators
 * @see createRequestReducer
 *
 * Ex.
 * const getEmployeeDuck = new RestDuck(execGetRequest, 'employee', GET_EMPLOYEE_SERVER_URL);
 * // Action creators
 * export const fetchEmployee = getEmployeeDuck.actionCreators.execRequest;
 * // Reducer
 * export const dataReducer = combineReducers(
 *   ...,
 *   getEmployeeDuck.reducer,
 * }
 * // Selectors
 * export const getDataContext = state => state.default.dataContext;
 * export const getEmployeeData = getEmployeeDuck.selectors.getRequestData(getDataContext);
 * export const getEmployeeStarted = getEmployeeDuck.selectors.getRequestStarted(getDataContext);
 * ...
 */
class RestDuck {
  constructor(name, path, restMethod, getApiContext) {
    this.restMethod = restMethod;
    this.name = name;
    this.path = path;
    this.getApiContext = getApiContext;
    this.$$duck = {}; // for class internal use
  }

  get actionTypes() {
    if (!this.$$duck.actionTypes) {
      this.$$duck.actionTypes = createRequestActionTypes(this.name, this.restMethod, this.path);
    }
    return this.$$duck.actionTypes;
  }

  get actionCreators() {
    if (!this.$$duck.actionCreators) {
      this.$$duck.actionCreators = createRequestActionCreators(this.restMethod, this.path, this.actionTypes);
    }
    return this.$$duck.actionCreators;
  }

  get reducer() {
    if (!this.$$duck.reducer) {
      this.$$duck.reducer = createRequestReducer(this.restMethod, this.name, this.actionTypes);
    }
    return this.$$duck.reducer;
  }

  get stateSelector() {
    return createSelector([this.getApiContext], restApiContext => restApiContext[this.name]);
  }
}

export default RestDuck;
```

**data/rest/restMethods.jsx**

```
import axios, { CancelToken } from 'axios';

const openPreview = (data) => {
  if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(data);
  } else {
    window.open(URL.createObjectURL(data));
  }
};

const cancellable = (config) => {
  let cancel;
  const request = axios({
    ...config,
    cancelToken: new CancelToken((c) => { cancel = c; })
  });
  request.cancel = cancel;
  return request.catch(error => (axios.isCancel(error) ? Promise.reject(new Error(null)) : Promise.reject(error)));
};

const defaultHeaders = {
  'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
  Pragma: 'no-cache',
  Expires: 0
};

const defaultPostHeaders = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
};

export const get = (url, params, responseType = 'json') => cancellable({
  url,
  params,
  responseType,
  method: 'get',
  headers: {
    ...defaultHeaders
  }
});

export const post = (url, data, responseType = 'json') => cancellable({
  url,
  responseType,
  data: JSON.stringify(data),
  method: 'post',
  headers: {
    ...defaultHeaders,
    ...defaultPostHeaders
  },
  cache: false
});

export const getBlob = (url, params) => get(url, params, 'blob');

export const postBlob = (url, data) => post(url, data, 'blob');

export const postAndOpenBlob = (url, data) => postBlob(url, data)
  .then((response) => {
    openPreview(response.data);
    return {
      ...response,
      data: 'blob opened as preview' // Don't waste memory by storing blob in state
    };
  });
```

I am not sure where to place and how to do mock api calls in this structure. I was thinking of making a mock api similiar to this [one](https://github.com/coryhouse/pluralsight-redux-app-used-to-build-script/tree/master/src/api), where I would mimick the ajax calls and store them in the redux, but just not sure how to do this in this kind of setup?

I have tried with making the mockApi folder and instead of using the restMethods, to use the file where I would write promises that would resolve the mockData. This is my attempt:

**mockRestMethods**

```
const employee = {
  name: 'Joe Doe'
}
const data = {
  employee 
};

export const get = item => new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve({ data: data[item] });
  }, 1000);
});
```

But, if I inspect what is returned as the `response.data` inside the **createRequestThunk** function in the **RestDuck** file I get `data: undefined` there. Why is that, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve on https://codesandbox.io/s/new?

Answer (score 1):

I may well have this wrong, but it seems like you are replacing

`export const get = (url, params, responseType = 'json') => cancellable({`

with `export const get = item => new Promise((resolve) => {` which has a different API.

Regardless, have you tried logging the value of `item` in the mock get function. I'm guessing it isn't "employee" which is the only property in `data`.

---

> Yes, that was my goal, to replace the call that was pointing to the backend API, with the call where I would return the mock data. I have tried to log the value of the item, but I get undefined

ok, so there's an awful lot of abstraction going on there. Id suggest starting by replacing `get` in `data/rest/restMethods.jsx` directly with a version that returns a promise, get it working, and then break it out. That way you're not dealing with too many unknowns at once.

Comment: Yes, that was my goal, to replace the call that was pointing to the backend API, with the call where I would return the mock data. I have tried to log the value of the ```item```, but I get ```undefined```.

Comment: I have tried directly replacing the method, but I get the same problem, I can't get the promise method to work.

Answer (score 1):

I had done similar using redux-saga. After debugging, I had found that there must be `data` property as root key. Here's how you should do:

```
const employee = {
  data: { // root key of employee
    items: [
      { name: 'Bhojendra' },
      { name: 'Rauniyar' }
    ]
  }
}

// and no need to use setTimeout, we're just resolving some constant data
export const getItems = item => new Promise(resolve => resolve(employee))
```

Now, I hope you know why data is `undefined` with your code.

Still not clear?

Response looks for the `data` property. That's it.